# Do I have to expect flash memory wear out when mounting a partition read-only?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, sd-card, raspberry-pi

I have created a simple kiosk-style Arch Linux installation on a Raspberry Pi that simply launches a web browser and shows some weather information.

To make the daily system bootup/shutdown routine as easy as possible, I mounted all partitions as read-only. This way, the system can be booted by switching on the power and shutdown by simply killing the power (no `sudo shutdown -h now` required). Also I created  a few special tmpfs partitions for parts of the system that need to be read-write. The system does not have any swap partition.

My concern now is, does this still wear out the SD card? In theory there should be no write-operations going on on the card, but could something else wear it out?

Comment: Besides aging? As long as time and electricity runs through the SD the card will eventually wear. When it will become unusable is another mystery.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question almost 10 years ago, and the project is still running every day. In the meantime the power adaptor had to be replaced twice, but SD card is still going strong.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/261384-32-does-reading-flash-drive-wear-down), it seems like the flash media will still wear over time, regardless of whether it is read or written to. However, reads should harm flash media much less than writes (if at all).